# Toolbar menu not showing up

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a requirement to show bottom navigation view, drawer menu in same layout.
Bottom navigation has three tabs each has its own content.The first bottom navigation tab contains a view pager with tablayout that has some conflict with the parent toolbar.

**Problem**
The child fragment toolbar hides the parent toolbar menu  **☰**   icon.

Here is the layout I am using.

**ParentLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**BottomNavFragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.telenor.magri.saatdo.activities.TabbedActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ScreenShot : Child layout having tablayout**

[image]

**ScreenShot : Child layout not having tablayout**

[image]

But the problem is toolbar menu icon for drawer is not showing up its hiding behind the child toolbar. So any idea what is problem in my layout.
Thanks

Comment: could you screenshot what it currently looks like?

Comment: @Aron Please check screenshots added.

Comment: Ahh alright hold on. I think I'll be able to help you

Comment: Follow this tutorial on creating bottom TabLayout navigation. 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Bottom-Navigation-Views
If you still need help let me know

Comment: I have implemented same thing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the Parent Activity `toolbar` in your Bottom Navigation View- Fragment 1

Change your layout to remove the toolbar..

**BottomNavFragment1.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabGravity="fill" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#3b5998" 
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" 
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#c8130d" 
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" /> 

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

In your activity layout use `layout_below` attribute for your `FrameLayout`

**ParentLayout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/appBarLayout"  //add this
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

otherwise it will replace the whole layout including the toolbar in your parent.

Comment: Hi @rafsanahmad007 I used your suggestion and here what i get the result. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnht47b1qx8wbe9/sss.PNG?dl=0                
Tabs have not action bar on top now and tabs overlapping menu icon and view pager overlapping tabs .

Comment: Hello..Welcome to stack overflow !..if the answer help mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign on left of the answer....